# Magento Server Response Time Very High - Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Our Mangeto 2 site is loading very slowly. Server response time is 2-4s.

We started using new relic to debug the issue.

We found the following loading very slowly .

##### Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::run

##### Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::launch

##### Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http::launch

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[New Relic Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWb3f.png)

Thanks,

Jack

We tried looking at our hardware but it is nowhere near maxing out. So we think it is code related

Comment: Hi, there can be many bottlenecks...  .... but is OPCACHE and [other magento ](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html) caching method enabled on server ....

Comment: Hello, yes we have cache enabled and varnish caching enabled too